# Embarking on a Tic Tac Toe journey with JavaFX

Tags: java, event-handling, tic-tac-toe, gui, javafx

On my educational trek through the capabilities of JavaFX, I thought it would be a valuable challenge to create Tic Tac Toe. It took me far longer than expected to get this far, but despite likely being even further from completion, I'd like a review on the current state of things and on anything my 'blind coding' unwittingly implemented unconventionally/inefficiently/just plain weirdly.

Some names may seem strange, but that could be due to my editing the image-related code to point to URLs rather than local files for the sake of this post.

**TicTacToe main class**:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {
    static Player player = Player.O_PLAYER;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button[] cells = new Button[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = new Button("",
            new ImageView(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/KAQPbPd.png")));
            registerOnAction(cells[i]);
        }

        GridPane board = new GridPane();
        for (int row = 1, col = 1, cell = 0; row <= 3; row++, col -=2) {
            board.add(cells[cell++], row, col++);
            board.add(cells[cell++], row, col++);
            board.add(cells[cell++], row, col);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(board);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("TicTacToe By Legato");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/gxhJkc0.png"));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Image retrieveMarker() {
        player = player == Player.X_PLAYER ? Player.O_PLAYER : Player.X_PLAYER;
        return player.marker();
    }

    private static void registerOnAction(Button button) {
        button.setOnAction(e ->
            button.setGraphic(new ImageView(retrieveMarker()))
        );
    } 
}
```

**Player enum**:

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public enum Player {
    X_PLAYER(new ImageView(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/HY6GeUY.png"))),
    O_PLAYER(new ImageView(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/KgHHxL6.png")));

    private final ImageView view;

    Player(ImageView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public Image marker() {
        return view.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name().charAt(0) + name().substring(2).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**Follow-ups**:

1. Completed [Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95706/tic-tac-towards-fx).
2. [Tic-Tactics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101253/ultimate-tic-tac-toe-a-k-a-tic-tactics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

> ```
> GridPane board = new GridPane();
> for (int row = 1, col = 1, cell = 0; row <= 3; row++, col -=2) {
>     board.add(cells[cell++], row, col++);
>     board.add(cells[cell++], row, col++);
>     board.add(cells[cell++], row, col);
> }
> ```

just looks odd. The initialiszing of 3 variables , incrementing of one of then and decrementing one of them in one single `for()` is a little bit to much IMHO.

how about using a more obvious loop like

```
for (int cell = 0; cell < cells.length; cell++) {
     board.add(cells[cell], cell / 3, cell % 3);
}
```

ok, one has to know if he/she reads this, that this will lead to

> (0 , 0 , 0)
>   (1 , 0 , 1)
>   (2 , 0 , 2)
>   (3 , 1 , 0)
>   (4 , 1 , 1)
>   (5 , 1 , 2)
>   ...

but it is less code without the strange incrementing and decrementing.

---

The creation of the buttons should be improved. Like now you are creating a new `Image` for each button. Just create the `Image` once and reuse it like

```
Image image = new Image("http://i.imgur.com/KAQPbPd.png");
Button[] cells = new Button[9];
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i] = new Button("", new ImageView(image);
    registerOnAction(cells[i]);
}
```

much better now, ins't it ?