# Ultimate Tic Tac Toe A.K.A. Tic Tactics

Tags: java, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe, community-challenge, javafx

My attempt at [this challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/weekend-challenge-reboot/1472#1472)., incorporating lessons from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95706/tic-tac-towards-fx), which turned out into a much bigger project than I anticipated, but it works. I'll definitely be refactoring most of this in the future, maybe going the MVC route. I tried a lot of new things here and am curious which are good and which are far removed from such.

Concerns:

1. Clarity in variable and method names.
2. Redundancies.
3. Anything unnecessarily convoluted.
4. General efficiency of this approach.
5. Edge Cases- Again, everything works, but I can't help but think there's something I've not encompassed in the code.
6. General improvements/feedback welcomed.

The code will follow the screenshot, with imports included to facilitate things.

[image: Game screen shot]

**The Winner enum**

```
public enum Winner {
    NONE(""),
    X("-fx-color: darkred;"),
    O("-fx-color: gold"),
    TIE("-fx-color: orangered;");

    private final String style;

    Winner(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }
}
```

**The Player enum**

```
public enum Player {
    X("-fx-text-fill: darkred;"),
    O("-fx-text-fill: gold;");

    private final String style;

    Player(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }
}
```

**The Position enum**

```
public enum Position {
    TOP_LEFT,
    TOP_MIDDLE,
    TOP_RIGHT,
    MIDDLE_LEFT,
    MIDDLE,
    MIDDLE_RIGHT,
    BOTTOM_LEFT,
    BOTTOM_MIDDLE,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT;
}
```

**The Tic Tac Toe Square Class**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class TicTacToeSquare {
    private Button button = new Button();
    private final int SQUARE_LENGTH = 70;

    TicTacToeSquare(TicTacticsGame game, TicTacToeBoard board, Position position) {
        button.setMinSize(SQUARE_LENGTH, SQUARE_LENGTH);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (button.getText().isEmpty()) {
                button.setText(game.getCurrentPlayer().toString());
                button.setStyle(game.getCurrentPlayer().getStyle());
                board.evaluateState();
                game.endTurn();
                game.board().disable();
                game.board().enable(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public Button button() {
        return button;
    }

    public boolean equivalentTo(TicTacToeSquare target) {
        return !button.getText().isEmpty() && button.getText().equals(target.button().getText());
    }

    public void reset() {
        button.setText("");
        button.setStyle("");
        button.setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

**The Tic Tac Toe Board Class**

```
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class TicTacToeBoard extends GridPane {
    private final int NUMBER_OF_SQUARES = 9;
    public int boardCounter;
    private TicTacToeSquare[] board = new TicTacToeSquare[NUMBER_OF_SQUARES];
    private TicTacticsGame game;
    private boolean captured = false;
    private Winner winner = Winner.NONE;

    TicTacToeBoard(TicTacticsGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = new TicTacToeSquare(this.game, this, Position.values()[i]);
            add(board[i].button(), i / 3, i % 3);
        }
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: cadetblue; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-border-radius: 5");
    }

    public void evaluateState() {
        for (int horizontal = 0, vertical = 0; horizontal < NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; horizontal += 3) {
            if (checkSet(vertical, vertical + 3, vertical++ + 6) 
            ||  checkSet(horizontal, horizontal + 1, horizontal + 2)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Diagonal
        if(checkSet(0, 4, 8) || checkSet(2, 4, 6)) {
            return;
        }

        if (++boardCounter == NUMBER_OF_SQUARES) {
            winner = Winner.TIE;
            captured = true;
            game.evaluateBoard();
            styleBoard();
            return;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkSet(int square1, int square2, int square3) {
        if (boardCounter >= 2) {
            if (board[square1].equivalentTo(board[square2]) 
            && board[square2].equivalentTo(board[square3])) {
                if (!captured) {
                    winner = board[square1].button().getText().equals("X") ? Winner.X : Winner.O;
                    captured = true;
                    game.evaluateBoard();
                }
                styleBoard();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equivalentTo(TicTacToeBoard target) {
        return winner != Winner.NONE && (winner == target.winner() || target.winner() == Winner.TIE);
    }

    public Winner winner() {
        return winner;
    }

    private void styleBoard() {
        for (TicTacToeSquare square : board) {
            square.button().setStyle(winner.getStyle());
        }
    }

    public void disable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i].button().setDisable(true);
        }
    }

    public void enable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i].button().setDisable(false);
        }
    }

    public boolean isCaptured() {
        return captured;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        for (TicTacToeSquare square : board) {
            if (square.button().getText().isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void reset() {
        captured = false;
        winner = Winner.NONE;
        boardCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i].reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Tic Tactics Board Class**

```
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class TicTacticsBoard extends GridPane {
    private final int NUMBER_OF_BOARDS = 9;
    public int boardCounter = 1;
    private TicTacToeBoard[] board = new TicTacToeBoard[NUMBER_OF_BOARDS];
    private TicTacticsGame game;

    TicTacticsBoard(TicTacticsGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = new TicTacToeBoard(this.game);
            add(board[i], i / 3, i % 3);
        }
        setHgap(5);
        setVgap(5);
    }

    public void evaluateState() {
        for (int horizontal = 0, vertical = 0; horizontal < NUMBER_OF_BOARDS; horizontal += 3) {
            if (checkSet(vertical, vertical + 3, vertical++ + 6) 
            ||  checkSet(horizontal, horizontal + 1, horizontal + 2)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // Diagonal
        if(checkSet(0, 4, 8) || checkSet(2, 4, 6)) {
            return;
        }

        if (++boardCounter == NUMBER_OF_BOARDS) {
            game.endPrompt("It's a tie!");
            return;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkSet(int innerBoard1, int innerBoard2, int innerBoard3) {
        if (boardCounter >= 3) {
            if (board[innerBoard1].equivalentTo(board[innerBoard2]) 
            && board[innerBoard2].equivalentTo(board[innerBoard3])) {
                game.endPrompt(game.checkWinner(board[innerBoard1].winner().toString()) + " wins!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void disable() {
        for (TicTacToeBoard b : board) {
            b.disable();
        }
    }

    public void enable(Position position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Position.values().length; i++) {
            if (position == Position.values()[i]) {
                if (board[i].isCaptured()) {
                    enableAll();
                } else {
                    board[i].enable();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void enableAll() {
        for (TicTacToeBoard b : board) {
            b.enable();
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        for (TicTacToeBoard b : board) {
            b.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Game Class**

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacticsGame extends BorderPane {
    private StringProperty xPlayer = new SimpleStringProperty("X player");
    private StringProperty oPlayer = new SimpleStringProperty("O player");
    private IntegerProperty xScore = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private IntegerProperty oScore = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private IntegerProperty tieScore = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private boolean scoreDisplayed;
    private Player currentPlayer = Player.X;
    private TicTacticsBoard board;

    TicTacticsGame(Stage stage) {
        board = new TicTacticsBoard(this);
        setTop(generateMenuBar(stage));
        setCenter(board);
    }

    private MenuBar generateMenuBar(Stage stage) {
        MenuItem newGameItem = new MenuItem("_New Game");
        newGameItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.N, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
        newGameItem.setOnAction(e -> newGame());

        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("E_xit");
        exitItem.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());

        Menu gameMenu = new Menu("_Game");
        gameMenu.getItems().addAll(newGameItem, exitItem);

        MenuItem addItem = new MenuItem("_Add player name(s)");
        addItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.A, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
        addItem.setOnAction(e -> addName(stage));

        Text xText = new Text();
        xText.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.concat(xPlayer).concat(" wins: ").concat(xScore.asString())
        );

        Text oText = new Text();
        oText.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.concat(oPlayer).concat(" wins: ").concat(oScore.asString())
        );

        Text tieText = new Text();
        tieText.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.concat("Ties: ").concat(tieScore.asString())
        );

        VBox scoreLayout = new VBox(5);
        scoreLayout.getChildren().addAll(xText, oText, tieText);
        scoreLayout.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        scoreLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        MenuItem trackItem = new MenuItem("_Toggle score display");
        trackItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.T, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
        trackItem.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!scoreDisplayed) {
                setRight(scoreLayout);
                scoreDisplayed = true;
                stage.sizeToScene();
            } else {
                setRight(null);
                scoreDisplayed = false;
                stage.sizeToScene();
            }
        });

        MenuItem resetItem = new MenuItem("_Reset score");
        resetItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.R, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
        resetItem.setOnAction( e -> {
            xScore.set(0);
            oScore.set(0);
            tieScore.set(0);
        });

        Menu scoreMenu = new Menu("_Score");
        scoreMenu.getItems().addAll(
            addItem,
            trackItem,
            resetItem
        );

        MenuItem howToItem = new MenuItem("How to _play");
        howToItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.H, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
        howToItem.setOnAction(e -> showGameRules());

        Menu helpMenu = new Menu("_Help");
        helpMenu.getItems().add(howToItem);

        activateMnemonics(
            gameMenu,
            newGameItem,
            exitItem,
            scoreMenu,
            addItem,
            trackItem,
            resetItem,
            helpMenu,
            howToItem
        );

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(gameMenu, scoreMenu, helpMenu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    public void endPrompt(String message) {
        board.disable();

        if (message.equals("It's a tie!")) {
            tieScore.setValue(tieScore.getValue() + 1);
        }

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Label label = new Label(message);
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");

        final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 80;

        Button reset = new Button("New Round");
        reset.setMinWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH);
        reset.setOnAction(e -> {
            stage.close();
            newRound();
        });
        reset.setDefaultButton(true);

        Button quit = new Button("Quit");
        quit.setMinWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH);
        quit.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());

        HBox gameLayout = new HBox(5);
        gameLayout.getChildren().addAll(reset, quit);
        gameLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox layout = new VBox(5);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, gameLayout);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 175 + new Text(message).getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), 75));
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setTitle("Game Over");
        stage.show();
    }

    public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    private void activateMnemonics(MenuItem... items) {
        for (MenuItem item : items) {
            item.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        }
    }

    private void newGame() {
        board.boardCounter = 0;
        currentPlayer = Player.X;
        board.reset();
    }

    private void newRound() {
        board.boardCounter = 0;
        board.reset();
    }

    private void addName(Stage primaryStage) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Label xName = new Label("Enter X player: ");
        GridPane.setConstraints(xName, 0, 0);
        TextField xPlayerField = new TextField();
        GridPane.setConstraints(xPlayerField, 1, 0);

        Label oName = new Label("Enter O player: ");
        GridPane.setConstraints(oName, 0, 1);
        TextField oPlayerField = new TextField();
        GridPane.setConstraints(oPlayerField, 1, 1);

        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setOnAction(e -> {
            String xString = xPlayerField.getText();
            String oString = oPlayerField.getText();
            if (!xString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").isEmpty()) {
                xPlayer.setValue(xString);
            }
            if (!oString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").isEmpty()) {
                oPlayer.setValue(oString);
            }
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            stage.close();
        });
        submit.setDefaultButton(true);
        GridPane.setConstraints(submit, 0, 2);

        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(
            xName,
            xPlayerField,
            oName,
            oPlayerField,
            submit
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.setTitle("Set name(s): ");
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public String checkWinner(String winner) {
        if (winner.equals("X")) {
            xScore.setValue(xScore.getValue() + 1);
            return xPlayer.getValue();
        } else {
            oScore.setValue(oScore.getValue() + 1);
            return oPlayer.getValue();
        }
    }

    public void showGameRules() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        TextArea area = new TextArea();
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setText("1. Each turn, you mark one of the small squares."
            + "\n2. When you get three in a row on a small board, you’ve won that board."
            + "\n3. To win the game, you need to win three small boards in a row."
            + "\n4. Tied boards may count for either X or O."
            + "\n\nYou don't get to pick the board you play on:"
            + "\n*Whichever square your opponent picks corresponds to the board you must play in"
            + "\n*If your opponent sends you to an already won board, you may play anywhere");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(area));
        stage.setTitle("Rules");
        stage.show();
    }

    public void endTurn() {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer == Player.X ? Player.O : Player.X;
    }

    public void evaluateBoard() {
        board.evaluateState();
    }

    public TicTacticsBoard board() {
        return board;
    }
}
```

**Class to run it**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTactics extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Tic Tactics by Legato");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new TicTacticsGame(stage)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Feel free to [try it](https://github.com/Javaliant/TicTactics/blob/master/Tic%20Tactics.exe?raw=true).
Here's a [jar](https://github.com/Javaliant/TicTactics/blob/master/Tic%20Tactics.jar?raw=true) for those that can't run executables.
and the [Github repo](https://github.com/Javaliant/TicTactics) where it will be maintained.

Answer (score 3):

**`final` Keyword**

The `Game`, `Tic Tac Toe Board`, `Tic Tac Toe Board`, all have fields which are assigned but never reassigned,

```
private StringProperty xPlayer = new SimpleStringProperty("X player");
private StringProperty oPlayer = new SimpleStringProperty("O player");
private TicTacticsGame game;
private Button button = new Button();
```

They could all use the `final` keyword.

**Generally**

The code is fairly easy to read, you follow most conventions. Overall a pleasant surprise to look at.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by separating initialization and launch here?

Comment: Generally speaking (from my experience and feedback gathered here) you want to different between initialization and launch, Meaning you want to separate `launch`, `start` and so on; from `main`. Just like `thread` is handled.

Comment: In that case I have to disagree with you, this is how it is typically done in JavaFX applications, I see no problem with that.

Comment: Late comment; however it seems that you are right. I stand corrected. I've now updated it to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

### Streamline logic

There are several cases where some logic is unnecessarily repeated and /or could be simplified. e.g. In the following,

```
trackItem.setOnAction(e -> {
     if (!scoreDisplayed) {
            setRight(scoreLayout);
            scoreDisplayed = true;
            stage.sizeToScene();
     } else {
            setRight(null);
            scoreDisplayed = false;
            stage.sizeToScene();
     }
});
```

In both cases, `stage.SsizeToScene()` is invoked it should be independent of control flow. Similarly, notice that setting `scoreDisplayed` to true in one case and false in the other is really just inverting the current value. The only thing actually dependent is the `setRight` method and that is straightforward enough for the conditional operator.

```
trackItem.setOnAction(e -> {
    setRight(scoreDisplayed ? null : scoreLayout);
    scoreDisplayed = !scoreDisplayed;
    stage.sizeToScene();
 });
```

There are also cases where some objects are closely coupled they may merit clustering into another. For instance, take the proceeding:

```
private StringProperty xPlayer = new SimpleStringProperty("X player");
private IntegerProperty xScore = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

Text xText = new Text();
        xText.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.concat(xPlayer).concat(" wins: ").concat(xScore.asString())
        );
```

This is all to represent the idea of a player, their score, and what text displays. This exact pattern is repeated for `oPlayer`, `oScore` and `oText` While largely a design decision, it would further simplify the code if these were clustered together. Rather than a Player enum a Player class could be created to house this logic, renaming what is now `Player` to `PlayerStyle` which could also be included in the new `Player` class.